# Advantages / Disadvantages to websites generated with Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, json

Two good examples would be [google](http://google.com) and [facebook](http://facebook.com).

I have lately pondered the motivation for this approach. My best guess would be it almost completely separates the logic between your back-end language and the markup. Building up an array to send over in JSON format seems like a tidy way to maintain code, but what other elements am I missing here?

What are the advantages / disadvantages to this approach, and why are such large scale companies doing it?

Comment: I think this would fit better in [programmers.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main disadvantage is that you have some pain with content indexation of your site.

For Google you can somewhere solve the problem by using Crawling scheme. Google supports crawling that allows you to index dynamically (without page reload) generated content of your page.

To do this your virtual links must be addresses like so: http://yoursite.com/#!/register/. In this case Google requests to http://yoursite/register/ to index content of the address.

When clicking on virtual link there is no page reload. You can provide this by using *onclick*:

```
<a href='http://yoursite.com/#!/register/' onclick='showRegister()'>Register</a>
```

Virtual advantage is that content of a page changed without reloading of the page. In my practice I do not use Javascript generation to do this because I build my interface in fixed positions. When page reloads user does not notice anything because elements of the interface appears in expected places.

So, my opinion that using of dynamic page generation is a big pain. I think Google did it not to separate markup and backend (it's not a real problem, you can use complex structure of backend-frontend to do that) but to use advantages of convenient and nice representation for users.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages

- View state is kept on the client (removing load from the server)
- Partial refreshes of pages
- Server does not need to know about HTML which leads to a Service Oriented Architecture

Disadvantages

- Bookmarking (state in the URL) is harder to implement
- Making it searchable is still a work in progress
- Need a separate scheme to support non-JS users

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% understand your question, but I'll try my best here...

Google and Facebook both extensively use JavaScript across all of their websites and products.  Every major website on the web uses it.

JavaScript is the technology used to modify the *behavior* of websites.
HTML => defines structure and elements

CSS => styling the elements

Scripting languages => dynamically generating elements and filling them with data

JavaScript => modifies all of the above by interacting with the DOM, responding to events, and styling elements on the fly

This is the 'approach' as you call it to every website on the web today.  There are no alternatives to JavaScript/HTML/CSS.  You can change the database or scripting language used, but JavaScript/HTML/CSS is a constant.

Comment: Ha.. yes I am a web developer. My questions are the advantages / disadvantages to this approach for large scale web applications? As opposed to having php generate the output via an MVC style architecture. This is a more standard approach, so I wonder why facebook / google choose this very javascript heavy approach.

Comment: Well I'm totally guessing here, but I would assume they are in fact using an MVC architecture in conjunction with lots of JavaScript. Actually, backbone.js, an MVC framework for your javascript, is becoming very popular so many sites have two MVC frameworks at work.  But no matter what your backend looks like, you still need javascript if you want any 'snappy' on-page application-like UI stuff to happen like AJAX.  No server-side technology can replace that.  You need client-side technology to get all that lovely UI, and that would be javascript.

Comment: I just figure this approach somewhat breaks your typical MVC. I mean, it pretty much eliminates the need for a view. Just JSON.

Comment: Well ideally you're creating a website that works with javascript off as well.  So the views are needed for that.  But, yes, you're right, ultimately what you end up with are views more or less just available for JavaScript consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example of a simple form validation ...

client sends a request to a server ... the server will execute the server side code containing validation logic and in a response ...the server will send the result to  the client ....

if the client has the capability to execute/process (that can be executed on the client side ...) the form ...(perform validation)..the client wont need send request to the server ...and wait for the server to respond to that request ...

Comment: You need to validate on the server, so this isn't the best example

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to take a look at Google Page Speed best practice http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/speed/page-speed/ to see what are the factors that makes a good page ... generating a page with javascript seems cool because of separation of ui and logic  , but it is a totally inefficient in practice